# progress 4gl - .ped file

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Whenever I try ***"THIS-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME"*** to display the current .p file I am working with , the result I always get is a ***.ped file***. I would like to know what a .ped file is and the ways to display the filename that is, the name of the .p file in my program.

Answer (score 5):

When you run a program directly from the Procedure Editor, it might even be an unsaved version of the program, Progress creates a temporary file (.ped) with the content of the editor to be able to compile and run your program.
If you want to receive the proper file name, just run the procedure using `RUN prog.p` instead of running it directly from the Procedure editor.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to obtain the proper file name directly from the procedure editor?

Comment: Yes, save the program, open a new buffer in the editor and run it from there.